# how to melt the column with group by in python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, melt

I have data with 4 columns . I want to perform group by with melt.

```
data:
col1   col2   col3           col4
de1    do1    2020-11-24      vt1
de1    do1    2020-11-24      vt2
de1    do2    2020-11-24      vt1
de1    do2    2020-11-24      vt2
```

I want to get output like below:

```
col1 col2 col3        vt1   vt2 
de1   do1  2020-11-24  1     1
de1   do2  2020-11-24  1     1
```

I have tried like this

```
df1 = data.melt('col1','col2','col3').groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

I am geeting `key error: 'col1'`

I have tried with `melt(['col1','col2','col3')]`. I am getting error `key error: 'col4'`.

Please, help me to solve this.

Comment: can you provide us with the data. the dictionary or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it not be easier to do a pivot_table?

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':['de1','de1','de1','de1'],
        'col2':['do1','do1','do2','do2'],
        'col3':['2020-11-24','2020-11-24','2020-11-24','2020-11-24'],
        'col4':['vt1','vt2','vt1','vt2']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
pivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['col1','col2','col3'], columns=['col4'],
                        aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).reset_index()

print(pivot)
```

result:

```
      col1 col2        col3  vt1  vt2
0     de1  do1  2020-11-24    1    1
1     de1  do2  2020-11-24    1    1
```

***Explanation of what is happening***

First your table will have as `index` Col1 to 3, then Col4 will be used to transform its values into new columns, and `aggfunc` will provide the `count` for each one of the values (extracted from col4). `Missing values` will receive 0 and the `reset_index` at the end is to give the table a better shape (`not needed`).

Comment: Thank you. SImple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does it solves your problem?

```
aux = df.melt(id_vars=['col1','col2', 'col3'], value_vars=['val'])
aux['count'] = 1
aux.pivot(index = ['col1','col2','col3'], columns='value',values='count' )
```

Answer (score 0):

This solutions returns also the correct names for the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["de1", "de1", "de1", "de1"],
    "col2": ["do1", "do1", "do2", "do2"],
    "col3": ["2020-11-24", "2020-11-24", "2020-11-24", "2020-11-24"],
    "col4": ["vt1", "vt2", "vt1", "vt2"]
})
df['count'] = 1
group_df = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index(level=[0,1,2])
group_df.columns = list(group_df.columns.get_level_values(0))[:3] + list(group_df.columns.get_level_values(1))[3:]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2        col3  vt1  vt2
0  de1  do1  2020-11-24    1    1
1  de1  do2  2020-11-24    1    1
```